Informix python package :pip install ifxpy error in IfxPy setup command: use_2to3 is invalid
pip install ifxpy
Collecting ifxpy
  Using cached IfxPy-3.0.5.tar.gz (155 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      C:\Users\kon6369\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_p7q_hbs\ifxpy_56684d68edfd4eb186b23478fe6d69f0\setup.py:175: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\l'
        library_dirs = [ py_home + '\libs', csdk_home + '\lib'],
      C:\Users\kon6369\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_p7q_hbs\ifxpy_56684d68edfd4eb186b23478fe6d69f0\setup.py:175: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\l'
        library_dirs = [ py_home + '\libs', csdk_home + '\lib'],
      Detected 64-bit Python
      Downloading : https://hcl-onedb.github.io/odbc/OneDB-Win64-ODBC-Driver.zip
      **error in IfxPy setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.**
      Extracting Windows ODBC files : https://hcl-onedb.github.io/odbc/OneDB-Win64-ODBC-Driver.zip
      Smart Triggers are enabled.
      [end of output]

pip install ifxpy
I need this package to install
Python 3.12.3
pip 24.0
wheel 0.43.0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

ifxpy is not supported in python 3.12
Official document says it is supported till python 3.7


https://pypi.org/project/IfxPy/

You need to install 3.7 separately.
